# Could not AOT the assembly for Microsoft.CSharp.dll on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, .net-assembly

When I try to build my Xamarin iOS project, I get the error :
" Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/myApp.iOS/hugeNumbers/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/3-Build/Microsoft.CSharp.dll' "

I've found in some other posts this is due to the package Newtonsoft.Json, but it is supposed to be fixed since a while ago.

I am trying to build my project on Visual Studio 2019 on Windows, synchronized with my Mac in order to launch on iPhone.

Any help please ?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/introducing-xamarin-ios-interpreter/

Comment: Thank you, I am taking a look at this, and I come back then.

Comment: Thank you, it is working ! Now I get another issue  "condition 'klass' not met" but I am going to start another question for this. Thank you again !

Comment: Same issue with the Microsoft.Graph library: MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/X/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/XX.App.iOS/1a642eb0dcec349e811e062b2a3b5a3080bb2e5d61650f80da243de43776c605/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/3-Build/Microsoft.Graph.dll'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Lex Li, here are the steps that made it works for me :

1- Download from [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/introducing-xamarin-ios-interpreter/) a installer for AOT (available for Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio for Mac 8.0

2- Launch the installer and follow the steps

3- On your project Xamarin.iOS (myApp.iOS), right click > settings

4- Go to Build iOS, and at the bottom of the page, add " --interpreter " in the section Additional mtouch arguments

5- Build again, and it should work.

Comment: This doesn't work as of Visual Studio 16.4.5. I get "Install Error : System.InvalidOperationException: Installation of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Android.DeviceManager failed. The extension has a lower version than required by Visual Studio.  Please install the extension from Visual Studio Installer instead."

Comment: You saved my as*, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Delete the app on phone or emulator.
Clean and rebuild solutions.
The redeploy again.

Comment: The app is not installed on the phone, it does not appear anywhere... Therefore I can't, delete the app.

Comment: The problem is the release build not the debug mode

Answer (score 0):

```
<MtouchExtraArgs>--interpreter=FSharp.Core ...</MtouchExtraArgs>
<MtouchInterpreter>-all</MtouchInterpreter>
```

and

```
<MtouchExtraArgs>--linkskip=FSharp.Core ...</MtouchExtraArgs>
```

both work for me in https://github.com/xperiandri/Elmish.Uno/

Comment: That did not work, same error message: Could not AOT the assembly '/.../iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/3-Build/Microsoft.Graph.dll'

Comment: By putting `Microsoft.Graph` instead of `FSharp.Core` into the code above?

Comment: Yes tried that of course, the solution below worked!

Comment: Do you mean mine or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553279/1149328)?